# "runtime error 1004 method range of object _global failed" VBA error

Tags: vba, runtime

Please help with the error:

> runtime error 1004 method range of object _global failed

That I recieve in this vba.

I have around 10 more VBAs before this one, none of them return an error, but this one (they are identical, only page numbers a different):

```
Sub actualizare()
Dim lastRw1, lastRw2, nxtRw, m
Dim StartRow, x
Dim StartDate As String
Dim FndRw As String

lastRw1 = Sheets(11).Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

StartDate = Range("908!A21").Value

For StartRow = 1 To lastRw1
If Range("19_01!B" & StartRow).Value = StartDate Then

FndRw = StartRow
Exit For
End If
Next

***Range("19_01!AM" & FndRw & ":AM" & lastRw1).ClearContents***

lastRw2 = Sheets(15).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For nxtRw = 1 To lastRw2

With Sheets(11).Range("B2000:B" & lastRw1)

Set m = .Find(Sheets(15).Range("A" & nxtRw), lookat:=xlWhole)

If Not m Is Nothing Then
Sheets(15).Range("B" & nxtRw).Copy _
Sheets(11).Range("AM" & m.Row)

End If
End With
Next
End Sub
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
If FndRw = vbNullString then Stop
Worksheets("19_01").Range("AM" & FndRw & ":AM" & lastRw1).ClearContents
```

And always make sure that you refer to the correct worksheet and specify the type of your variables.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will correct the names. The problem is that the VBA awaits to find a date (dd/mm/yyyy) in cell a21 from sheet 908. But there are some days when i have no request in this page. Instead of a date, the client is writing "no forecast available". When the code find this text instead of a date, it gives me the "runtime error 1004".

Is it possible to modify the code so that, if it does not find a date in sheet 908, cell A21, to ignore that line and not try to import my data?